# How to fix a slide toolbar in twitter-bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fixed sidebar navigation in fluid twitter bootstrap 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9350818/fixed-sidebar-navigation-in-fluid-twitter-bootstrap-2-0)

ref to http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/fluid.html

is there any css class in twitter-bootstrap which can fix the sidebar, just like the fixed nav-bar.

that is to say: just scroll the right content, but sidebar is still in sight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[I have answered this question before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9351158/680398) and what it entails is a set of new classes to fix your sidebar and another to push your content container away from it.

Comment: If you have answered a question before, please don't answer it again but close the duplicate question.