# CSS Height 100% without knowing height of header

Tags: html, css, height

I know this question was asked many times, but it's still unfigurable for me. Anyway I have a code like this:

```
<div id="header">
Here are many different div's with various position (relative, absolute, static, etc).
</div>
<div id="content">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="upper">
         Some dummy content
      </div>
      <div class="lower">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now, how can I set for example `.upper` div to fit into the window, since I have no idea what's the height of header?

Comment: Without setting a fixed `height` to `#header`, this can only be done via scripting or altering your structure so the `#header` is inside `#upper` with `#upper`, `#inner`, `#row`, `#content`, `body`, and `html` having a `height` of 100%. Which option would you prefer to pursue? If the script, do you want plain JavaScript, or jQuery?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Force Child Div to 100% of Parent's Div Without Specifying Parent's Height?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122381/how-to-force-child-div-to-100-of-parents-div-without-specifying-parents-heigh)

Comment: @IkoTikashi it doesn't really matter what the css is. It's just a general example and question of how to handle this thing no matter what the css is. There are plenty of nested containers with different width and height an d position.

Comment: Try looking at the `display: table` usage from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17618682/1654265), it *might* help widening your horizon :) But beware of cross-browser compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

You could work with media querys

```
@media(min-height: 500px){
    .upper{
        display: none;
    }
}
```

means if the height of `.upper` is at least 500px high it will be displayed. You could also set it from `position: fixed;` (what I suppose it is) to `position: absolute;` if the window is too small, then you'd have to scroll instead of squashing your content

Comment: I don;t wanna display it conditionally. I want it to be always visible and always set to the bottom of the page, whatever the window height is.

Comment: I suppose it is "position: fixed"? Set it to "absolute" if the window gets to small

Comment: Ok, so what if I have some divs beneath this #content tag? It goes up and it's overlay the #content.

Comment: Usually the divs that are beneath (NOT inside) the #content should stay outside of it. If its width is 100% they should always stay beneath it.