# Fixed sidebar in twitter bootstrap 2.0 results in overlap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-position

When I follow all 3 options in the top answer in this post:
[Fixed sidebar navigation in fluid twitter bootstrap 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9350818/fixed-sidebar-navigation-in-fluid-twitter-bootstrap-2-0/)

The sidebar is indeed fixed but the content in the other div in the row (the span9) is overlapped by the sidebar. When I remove the CSS additions, the overlap is gone. I've triple-checked my html to make sure there's now hanging divs and everything seems to check out.

Has the core bootstrap CSS changed in a material way or am I missing something?

Here's a screencap:
[image]

Comment: I'm working on getting the full code up but I may have just realized that in the cited answer, it is mentioned but not reflected in the suggested HTML that an offset class be added to the content div. So should the content div be <div class="span9 offset 4"> (instead of just span9) assuming the sidenav is span3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem myself by using the offset class as mentioned in my comment. It is referenced by not used in the answer to the cited questions. Thanks for everyone's help/editing.