# jQuery Sticky Div and scroll to top plugins working on one page only

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, web-applications, plugins

I am building a site that uses infinite scroll. Because the page can grow so long I have added a plugin that keeps the sidebar and advertizement scrolling down with you so It is always in view. Also after the user scrolls 100 pixels, a scroll to top button shows in the bottom right corner.

The site is written python and there is a main template that contains the jquery, nav, and sidebar and then multiple other templates that serve up the main content on the site.

My problem is that these two plugins are only working on 1 page and not the others, specifically the ones that really need the sticky div and scroll to top functionality.

This is the main page where it is not working: http://goo.gl/GKnfW

The page you land on after you upload an image here: http://goo.gl/UKKnO
is where the plugins are working properly.

I have run my site through a vaildator and corrected all the errors that might cause this problem.

Help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Link2 does not work either... BTW: A bit of code will helps you/us more than thousands of words ;)

Answer (score 0):

Many times this problem comes from a jQuery conflict somewhere.  Do you have any other libraries that could be conflicting?

Try wrapping your jQuery code like this `jQuery(document).ready(function(){ .....` instead of using the $, or using noConflict `jQuery.noConflict();`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easier solution here is to just make your sidebar fixed.  I noticed you are using bootstrap - check out the jsfiddle on this corresponding stackoverflow post.  Use the CSS shown there and it should get you the functionality you want in a much easier, non-JS implementation.

See here:
[Fixed sidebar navigation in fluid twitter bootstrap 2.0 (StackOverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9350818/fixed-sidebar-navigation-in-fluid-twitter-bootstrap-2-0)