# How to auto position sidenav in twitter bootstrap while sliding

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been trying to position sidenav using answers from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9350818/fixed-sidebar-navigation-in-fluid-twitter-bootstrap-2-0). Currently I'm able to fix the menu position to the page simply by:

```
<div style="position: fixed" ..>
  ..
</div>
```

or by adding this to the corresponding css rule. It works ok but the position start right after the jumbotron subhead and stays there when I scroll. I want it not to override the jumbotron at the top of the page and move to a fixed position at the top of the page when I scroll down (just like in the [documentation page](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/getting-started.html) except that I don't care about active highlights)

I have tried to copy the source of the documentation and added `docs.css` file in the page as well but it doesn't work for some reason. How can I do this?

**EDIT**

Here's a figure to make it clear

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is something to get you started: http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/s9XpJ/

I've used the [affix behaviour](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#affix) which is really interesting and gives you lots of options.

The important stuff in my example is in the HTML I've specified the div I want to spy on

```
<div "span3" id="side-nav" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="200">
 <!-- nav here -->
</div>
```

and specified the data-offset-top which is the distance you need to scroll before the div is affixed.

The class **affix** will be added to the div when it's affixed so in the CSS I've specified what happens then.

```
#side-nav.affix{
top:10px;
}
```

You generally need to reposition the affixed div on the page because by default bootstrap will define its position as **fixed** which brings it out of normal flow.

I also added some CSS using media requests to fine tune what happens as the view point narrows. The example on the Bootstrap site removes the affixed behaviour of the side-nav for the narrowest screens. I repeated that here.

Good luck!