# side nav background shrinks while content doesn't

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, background, overflow

I'm making a quick and dirty website for a university wed design module. The website isn't intended to work but instead to be used as a tool to demonstrate how the proposed design would look and operate.

I have used a bootstrap template and things have gotten a bit messy.

**The Problem:**

I have a navigation bar on the left of each page with an image as a background. if i re-size my browser window the content remains the same height (as it should) but the background disappears from the bottom.

here's a link to the website:
http://www.wareisjoe.com/bistro/

I don't know if this is due to poorly formed HTML or a css issue. any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9350818/fixed-sidebar-navigation-in-fluid-twitter-bootstrap-2-0, I think this is what you wanted.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't implemented this yet but it looks like it should work!

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with bootstrap because it makes it able to use the layout on your phone.
the lower the width the more it's going to move to phone version.