# Bootstrap3: Content responsive

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

As you can see in this example:

http://bootply.com/render/92511

I have a simple structure with two main area: navigation and content.
If you try to resize the browser you can see that the content is responsive only up to a certain point. For a phone view the content is not responsive and i need to move right the read it.

The question is: how can i make that content completely responsive, no matter the size?

Thank you

**EDIT**: Here is the Html and Css:  http://bootply.com/92511

Comment: can you just post the code... html

Comment: If you want it to be completely responsive you can't have a fixed left nav.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove the `min-width:600px;`from CSS and also remove the col-md-.., just use col-xs-.. only, so it would be fully responsive in any device

Comment: Thanks is working. I have changed to col-xs-3 to keep to a minimum size the navigation. But i have seen that i have to keep the col-md otherwise there are problems in the tablet view (the col-xs completely disappear)